# System::Object^ sender

Tags: c++-cli

I have a panel1 and on it pictureBox1. By default panel1 is parent of pictureBox1. pictureBox1's location 30, 30. I put 4 labels on pictureBox1 and their coordinates by default determined by panel1.For all labels i designate one event, All_ParentChanged. With Form1_Load event (or in constructor) I designate pictureBox1 as a parent of all labels, like label1->Parent = pictureBox1... This automatically initializes All_ParentChanged event. And in this event I change coordinates of all labels +40 pxls, +40 pxls. I do it like this:

```
label1->Location = Point(label1->Left + 40, label1->Top + 40);
label2->Location = Point(label2->Left + 40, label2->Top + 40);
label3->Location = Point(label3->Left + 40, label3->Top + 40);
label4->Location = Point(label4->Left + 40, label4->Top + 40);`
```

But guess that i have 100 labels. It's a lot of trash to write a line for all of them. So what i want to ask is can I use a sender of System::Object to do it with one line, like:

```
sender->Location = Point(sender->Left + 40, sender->Top + 40);
```

I used this code but it says Location isn't member of System::Object. Please help me people. In advance thanks.

Comment: Your title does not describe your question in the slightest.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that:

```
Label^ senderLabel = safe_cast<Label^>(sender);
senderLabel->Location = Point(senderLabel->Left + 40, senderLabel->Top + 40);
```

But the `ParentChanged` event seems like the wrong place to do this.  Why are all the locations wrong in the designer?  Could you make an array with all your labels, thus allowing you to do everything to multiple labels (set `Parent` for the entire array, no problem.  Adjust location, no problem)